# Wordpress: Create a customized role / user

Tags: wordpress, customization, roles

I’m farely new to Wordpress but are working on putting a page together which has a very simple purpose. I’m creating it for a customer with little or none IT experience so I want to create a user he can use to login and edit his pages – and **nothing** more. No settings, no comments, no posts, no links, no nothing, just create, delete and edit pages and maybe edit his own profile or at least his E-mail and password.

I can see that wordpress has some predefined roles for users but none of them completely does what I want and they either has to little or to many rights. I’ve been looking at the wordpress page http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities but can’t seem to get a clear answer.

Is it in any way possible for me to create my own user role (e.g. customer) where I can set the rights I want for him?

Thanks

Sincerely
Mestika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [Role Manager](http://www.im-web-gefunden.de/wordpress-plugins/role-manager/) plugin. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Fantastic, I was looking all over for such a plugin - thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide all unnecessary options from the admin panel. Use [Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/) plugin.